# Is this small business database design on the right path?

Tags: database-design, mariadb, database-diagrams

I am designing a database for a small business that would like to use this system for a very long time, meaning they expect to maintain and grow the system but they want to start off well.  This is not a complete design, but before I go too far with the design portion I would like to know if this design, specifically with the way I have tables separated and grouped, is efficient (computing resources, data storage/retrieval).  This system will be run locally, with no "internet" access.  It will be accessed via a html/css/php interface on a LAN/WAN via a VPN.  The server will be a debian (v12 currently) linux system running MariaDB version 10.11.3-MariaDB-1 currently.  If it matters, apache will be the web server.

The following is the psuedo code, taken from dbdiagram.io (it includes color references which can be viewed in the attached image) (notes/comments are incomplete here):

```
// The entities table is the list of possible users, clients, admins, et cetera.
Table entity  [headercolor: #3498db] {
  entity_id int [pk]
  username varchar(16)
  passphrase varchar
  create_stamp timestamp
  entity_avatars_id int [ref: > entity_avatars.entity_avatars_id]
}

// The journal table is all-knowing.
// Every action will also need to update this journal table.
Table journal  [headercolor: #c0392b] {
  journal_id int [pk]
  log_timestamp timestamp
  log_entity varchar // entity.id
  log_field varchar
  log_orig varchar
  log_mod varchar
}

Table entity_names  [headercolor: #3498db] {
  entity_names_id int [pk]
  // Need to check for combo of fname, lname matches.
  fname varchar(32)
  mname varchar(32)
  lname varchar(32)
  entity_id int [ref: > entity.entity_id]
}

Table entity_gender  [headercolor: #3498db] {
  entity_gender_id int [pk]
  gender varchar(16)
  entity_id int [ref: > entity.entity_id]
}

Table entity_prefix  [headercolor: #3498db] {
  entity_prefix_id int [pk]
  prefix_name varchar(16)
  entity_id int [ref: > entity.entity_id]
}

Table entity_suffix  [headercolor: #3498db] {
  entity_suffix_id int [pk]
  suffix_name varchar(16)
  entity_id int [ref: > entity.entity_id]
}

Table entity_nicks  [headercolor: #3498db] {
  entity_nicks_id int [pk]
  nickname varchar(32)
  entity_id int [ref: > entity.entity_id]
}

Table entity_dob  [headercolor: #3498db] {
  entity_dob_id int [pk]
  date_of_birth date
  entity_id int [ref: > entity.entity_id]
}

Table entity_avatars [headercolor: #3498db] {
  entity_avatars_id int [pk]
  avatar blob
}

// client,vendor,employee...
Table groups  [headercolor: #f39c12] {
  groups_id int [pk]
  group_name varchar
  entity_id int [ref: > entity.entity_id]
}

// The telephone_number table allows for multiple entities to use a single number.
Table telephone_number  [headercolor: #27ae60] {
  telephone_number_id int [pk]
  number int [not null]
  type_name_id int [ref: > telephone_type.telephone_type_id]
  entity_id int [ref: > entity.entity_id]
}

// mobile,office,home,support...
Table telephone_type  [headercolor: #27ae60] {
  telephone_type_id int [pk]
  type_name varchar
}

Table email_address {
  email_address_id int [pk]
  email_address varchar
  entity_id int [ref: > entity.entity_id]
}

Table physical_address {
  physical_address_id int [pk]
  address1 varchar
  address2 varchar
  city_id int [ref: > city.city_id]
  state_id int [ref: > state.state_id]
  zip_code_id int [ref: > zip_code.zip_code_id]
  entity_id int [ref: > entity.entity_id]
}

Table city {
  city_id int [pk]
  city_name varchar
  city_initials varchar
}

Table state {
  state_id int [pk]
  state_name varchar
  state_abbrev varchar
}

Table zip_code {
  zip_code_id int [pk]
  zip_code int
}

Table site_location {
  site_location_id int [pk]
  site_name varchar
  physical_address_id int [ref: > physical_address.physical_address_id]
}

Table vendors  [headercolor: #79AD51] {
  vendors_id int [pk]
  vendor_name varchar
  entity_id int [ref: > entity.entity_id]
}

Table timeclock [headercolor: #24BAB1] {
  timeclock_id int [pk]
  entity_id int [ref: > entity.entity_id]
  clockin datetime
  clockout datetime
  site_location_id int [ref: > site_location.site_location_id]
}

Table inventory_categories [headercolor: #79AD51] {
  inventory_categories_id int [pk]
  category_name varchar
  category_description varchar
  category_number varchar
  inventory_brands_id int [ref: > inventory_brands.inventory_brands_id]
  vendos_id int [ref: > vendors.vendors_id]
  category_markup float
}

Table inventory_brands [headercolor: #79AD51] {
  inventory_brands_id int [pk]
  brand_name varchar
  brand_markup float
}

Table inventory_products [headercolor: #79AD51] {
  inventory_products_id int [pk]
  product_cost float
  product_markup float
}

Table inventory_collections [headercolor: #79AD51] {
  inventory_collections_id int [pk]
  collection_name varchar
}

Table inventory_items [headercolor: #79AD51] {
  inventory_items_id int [pk]
  vendors_id int [ref: > vendors.vendors_id]
  inventory_categories_id int [ref: > inventory_categories.inventory_categories_id]
  inventory_products_id int [ref: > inventory_products.inventory_products_id]
  inventory_collections_id int [ref: > inventory_collections.inventory_collections_id]
  item_cost float
  item_markup float
  item_retail float
  item_status varchar
  item_name varchar
  item_description varchar
  item_invoice varchar
}

Table invoices [headercolor: #DE65C3] {
  invoices_id int [pk]
  inventory_items_id int [ref: > inventory_items.inventory_items_id]
  // figure out what should be recorded with the invoice
}

Table sales [headercolor: #2D6512] {
  // need to put transactions in a transactions table?
  sales_id int [pk]
  inventory_items_id int [ref: > inventory_items.inventory_items_id]
  sale_date datetime
}
```

I am asking for brutal honesty.  If I need to scrap this and start over, I would rather do so now versus in the future once I have invested more time into this and or once I have a system running on this.

T.Y.I.A.!

[image: current db design taken from dbdiagram.io]

Comment: What is the software supposed to do? Why do you think it is going to scale? Have you already tested the software and this small business and have you faced any issue with your current design?

Comment: The software is going to keep track of all employees, vendors, clients, inventory, sales and service transactions, as well as provide reports from these events.  I think it will scale as is because this current design breaks the data into very essential elements while providing flexibility.  I have not tested the software, as I am still designing the database from which the software will run.  The interface aspect has been created, but may be modified.  The software I am replacing is unsupported (company out of business), it is very old, and limited reporting.

Comment: So it's an ERP. This company is trying to replace the old and now unsupported ERP. Frankly I think you are trying to reinvent the wheel: there are so many ERP software out there, why creating a new one? Your diagram looks good to me. Maybe try to download an opensource ERP and copy the database design

Comment: Are you using cPanel? Because Softaculous offers WebERP https://www.softaculous.com/apps/erp/webERP . You can just sell that to the customer and you don't even have to maintain it. Or download any opensource ERP and sell your service to the customer. Why reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Here the demo: https://softaculous.com/demos/weberp and here a preview: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16T8JyqzIhQ

Comment: You might want to compare your data model with some of the ones you can see at [database answers](https://databases.biz/data-models/).